# Reduction of La(NO3)3 to La(NO2)3

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox

I'm writing a master's thesis on some lanthanide compounds, in particular those with $\ce{Ce^{+3}}$ and $\ce{La^{+3}}$, although my focus has now shifted to lanthanum, but I ran into a problem when I could not precipitate my anion, which is a coordination compound, with lanthanum so to solve this problem I modified my reaction setup to start with $\ce{La(NO2)3}$ instead of $\ce{NaNO2}$ so that when I want to precipitate the coordination compound I don't have those pesky sodium ions around.

The thing is, I only have a $\ce{La(NO3)3}$ in store, so I was wondering if there is a way to reduce the nitrate ion to nitrite without changing the lanthanide oxidation number.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish lanthanum $\ce{La}$ and lanthanides $\ce{Ln}$ as the element group from $\ce{Ce}$ to $\ce{Lu}$.  The former has redox potential $\ce{La/La^3+}$ about $\pu{-2,37 V}$, similar to $\ce{Mg}$. So no worries for $\ce{La^3+}$ to be reduced. It may matter for lanthanides forming $\ce{Ln^2+}$ ions. Check the respective redox potentials for $\ce{Ln^3+/Ln^2+}$ at [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)), the same for $\ce{NO3-/NO2-}$ and choose the reduction agens with suitable reduction kinetics for nitrates.

Comment: You have shifted the question from lanthanides to lanthanum, but not thoroughly. You have to choose: either lanthanum(La), either lanthanides(Ln). For La, reduction of lanthanum ions will not occur.

Comment: I've done so because I was asked to be more specific about the lanthanide. If possible a general response that serves for most if not all lanthanides would please me, if not, I'm satisfied with only La and Ce, since this are the focus of my thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zinc powder can reduce nitrate to nitrite, see [Morita and Nakamura[1]](https://doi.org/10.2116/bunsekikagaku.57.777). Lanthanum is much higher than zinc in the EMF series, so a side reaction of reducing the lanthanum ions will not occur. However, the reduction process may introduce zinc ions to the solution. Based on Pourbaix-diagram data, maintaining a near-neutral pH between 6 and 8 is suggested for precipitating the zinc as hydroxide while maintaining good solubility of the lanthanum ions.

**Reference**

1. Morita, Emi & Nakamura, Eiko. (2008). "Reduction of Nitrate to Nitrite by Using Zinc Powder for Determination of Total Nitrogen in Sea Water". *Bunseki Kagaku*. **57**. 777-781. 10.2116/bunsekikagaku.57.777.